# Mysql select alias in where clause

Tags: mysql, sql

I have problem with using alias in where clause.

I have tables like this:
[image]

I store users and they can send messages to each other. Messages data is stored in social_messages table, with core_users_sender and core_users_receiver ids.

Now when user logs in system I want to show the list of only those users with which he/she had conversation.

(logged in core_users.id is 6)
I use this query and get ids of friends with which user had conversations without problem:

```
SELECT
    messages.id,
    messages.status,
    messages.send_date,
    IF(
        core_users_sender = 6,
            core_users_receiver,
            core_users_sender
    ) as friend_id
FROM
    social_messages messages
WHERE
      messages.core_users_sender = 6
        OR
      messages.core_users_receiver = 6
GROUP BY
  friend_id
```

But problem is that when I try to get data from core_users table with friend_id and and use query:

```
SELECT
    messages.id,
    messages.status,
    messages.send_date,
    IF(
        core_users_sender = 6,
            core_users_receiver,
            core_users_sender
    ) as friend_id,
    users.fullname
FROM
    social_messages messages,
    core_users users
WHERE
      users.id = friend_id
      AND
      (
          messages.core_users_sender = 6
            OR
          messages.core_users_receiver = 6
      )
GROUP BY
  friend_id
```

I get error because friend_id cant be used in where clause because its calculated in select

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't uses aliases in the `where` clause. Use the original subquery

```
where users.id = IF(
                core_users_sender = 6,
                core_users_receiver,
                core_users_sender
        )
```

> It is not allowable to refer to a column alias in a WHERE clause, because the column value might not yet be determined when the WHERE clause is executed.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to reorder your query in this way :

```
SELECT
    messages.id,
    messages.status,
    messages.send_date,
    users.fullname,
    IF(
        messages.core_users_sender IS NOT NULL,
        messages.core_users_receiver,
        messages.core_users_sender
    ) as friend_id
FROM
    social_messages messages
    left join core_users users_sender
        on users_sender.id = messages.core_users_sender
        and messages.core_users_sender = 6
    left join core_users users_receiver
        on users_receiver.id = messages.core_users_receiver 
        and messages.core_users_receiver = 6

WHERE
    users_sender.id IS NOT NULL OR users_receiver.id IS NOT NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

You can alias your table and use it

```
        SELECT messages.*, users.fullname
        FROM
        (SELECT
            messages.id,
            messages.status,
            messages.send_date,
            IF(
                core_users_sender = 6,
                    core_users_receiver,
                    core_users_sender
            ) as friend_id
        FROM
            social_messages messages
        WHERE
              messages.core_users_sender = 6
                OR
              messages.core_users_receiver = 6
        GROUP BY
          friend_id) as `messages`
        JOIN
              core_users users
        ON
              users.id = messages.friend_id
```